# ¿Cómo abrir aplicación de mapas con una posición GPS específica en Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Tengo la url `https://www.google.com/maps/@41.3825581,2.1704375,16z`que posiciona Barcelona en el mapa, pero me encuentro que no sale digamos el apuntador de la dirección, solo te centra el mapa.

En mi dispositivo tengo varias apps de mapas:

- Cytymapper
- MAPS.ME
- Google Maps
- Google Earth

El código que tengo para lanzar el `Intent`:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/@41.3825581,2.1704375,16z");
if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(uri.toString())) {
   startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
}
```

Me sale un `ActionList` para escoger `Maps` o `Chrome`, si pulso sobre `Maps` me abre la aplicación `maps`, pero no me muestra con un indicador la posición, se centra en landmark y punto.

Si indico que se abre con `chrome`, sale otro `ActionList`, con las otras aplicaciones de mapas.

Mis dudas son:

- ¿Cómo hago para lanzar un `Intent` específico para que se puede abrir con las Apps de Mapas?
- ¿Cómo puedo visualizar el marcador de la posición dentro de el mapa?

**Solucionado:**

Para mostrar una localización con marcador y etiqueta

`geo:<lat>,<lon>?z=<zoom>&q=<lat>,<lon>(<label>)`

Para mostrar la ubicación de Barcelona

`geo:41.3825581,2.1704375?z=16&q=41.3825581,2.1704375(Barcelona)`

Para mostrar el `ActionList` que salgan todas las aplicaciones compatibles para posicionar una localización

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:41.3825581,2.1704375?z=16&q=41.3825581,2.1704375(Barcelona)");
startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Si se quiere mandar la posición directamente a la aplicación Google Maps

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:41.3825581,2.1704375?z=16&q=41.3825581,2.1704375(Barcelona)"));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Algo he descubierto mirando la Api de googlemaps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Para que se muestre el marcador de posición https://www.google.com/maps/place/41°22'57.2"N+2°10'13.6"E/@41.3834645,2.1691642,16z

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7405992/2573335) respuesta en SO en ingles:

La forma es esta:

```
Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo:41.382,2.170?z=16&q=41.382,2.170(Esta+Es+La+Etiqueta)");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intentUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: me parece que geo no es soportado por Uri.parse, he probado una estándar obtenida de wikipedia `geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35`y me da invalid uri

Comment: ese no es el formato, ese punto y coma no va. igual ahora lo voy a probar.

Comment: @mmeverdies uso URLUtil.isValidUrl(uri.toString() y eso es lo que me da invalido, sin eso funciona

Comment: @Webserveis creo que esto explica por que: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/webkit/URLUtil.java#URLUtil.isValidUrl%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer asi:

```
map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(xxxx,xxxx) , 14.0f) );
```

Las xxxx representan latitud y longitud y 14.0f el nivel de zoom.

Comment: Gracias, en principio lo quiero hacer externamente, mediante Intents, sin cargar el elemento de mapas, es decir que la app instalada por defecto de abrir una ubicación de mapas, si es google maps, google earth etc...

Answer (score 2):

https://www.google.com/maps/@41.3825581,2.1704375,16z

¿Cómo puedo visualizar el marcador de la posición dentro de el mapa?

No se si abra alguna manera mejor de hacer lo que pide, pero si entiendo su pregunta puede tratar alguno de los ejemplos siguientes, si es lo que busca podria implementarlo de alguna manera en su app, si no puede obtener las coordenadas en la siguiente Act, podria pasarcelas dentro del Intent y recuperarlas por ahi.

---

```
// latitude longitude

double latitude = 41;
double longitude = 2;

// marker
MarkerOptions miMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hola Webserveis");

// marker icono
miMarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mimarkericono)));

// marker
googleMap.addMarker(miMarker);
```

---

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hola Webserveis"));
}
```

---

¿Cómo hago para lanzar un Intent específico para que se puede abrir con las Apps de Mapas?

Sobre la parte que dice como abrir una app con un Intent, no se si esto es a lo que se refiere:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+_lat+","+_ltg+"&daddr="+destino_lat+","+destino_ltg)); //o la direccion/consulta que quiera "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ myLatitude  +"," + myLongitude +"("+ labLocation + ")&iwloc=A&hl=es"
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Gracias @Angel más o menos ya tengo la solución entre todos

Comment: @Webserveis me alegra que lo solucionara. por otra parte por la notificacion de su comentario, lei otra vez la pregunta y creo que interperte mal esta parte -> ...visualizar el marcador..., creia que queria mostrar un market de una posicion, pero no se si es eso lo que tambien queria. Saludos