# ¿Obtener indicaciones de un punto a otro maps android o json?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

¿hay alguna forma de obtener indicaciones de los pasos a seguir de un lugar a otro?, por ejemplo gira a la drecha con direccion a al av.tacna ,asi como se muestra en la imagen.
ya sea con sdk de android o con api web de salida json.[image: indicaciones a seguir]

Answer (score 0):

lo que pides maps te lo hace por defecto pero necesitas dos coordenadas o direcciones. Una vez calcules la distancia entre ellas(te recomiendo mirarte "Uri").
Aquí tienes bastante información:
[¿Cómo abrir aplicación de mapas con una posición GPS específica en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3145/c%C3%B3mo-abrir-aplicaci%C3%B3n-de-mapas-con-una-posici%C3%B3n-gps-espec%C3%ADfica-en-android)